# Using ExtractMsg in a loop?

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to write a script that will extract details from Outlook .msg files and append then to a .csv file. ExtractMsg (https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor) will process the messages one at a time, at the command line with 'python ExtractMsg.py message' but I can't work out how to use this to loop through all the messages in the directory.

I have tried:

```
import ExtractMsg
import glob
for message in glob.glob('*.msg'):
    print 'Reading', message
    ExtractMsg(message)
```

This gives "'module' object is not callable". I have tried to look at the  ExtractMsg module but the structure of it is beyond me at the moment. How can I make the module callable?

Comment: I would start by looking at the sample on the github project page, downloading the sample, and then running it. From that, you should either solve or get closer to solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExtractMsg(message)
```

You are trying to call module object - exactly what error message us telling you.

Perhaps you need to use ExtractMsg.Message class instead

```
msg = ExtractMsg.Message(message)
```

In the next link on the very bottom you will find example of usage

https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor/blob/master/ExtractMsg.py

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - the following sorted it:

```
import ExtractMsg
import glob
for message in glob.glob('*.msg'):
    print 'Reading', message
    msg = ExtractMsg.Message(message)
    body = msg._getStringStream('__substg1.0_1000')
    sender = msg._getStringStream('__substg1.0_0C1F')
```